# The surjectivity of the canonical projection map

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a subspace of a vector space $Y$.  Define the canonical projection map $$\pi: Y \to Y/X$$ by $$\pi(y) \mapsto \{y\} + \mid X \mid.$$  So if $S_0$ is a subspace of $S$, then for any coset in the quotient space $S/S_0$ determined by an arbitrary vector $s \in S$, $\pi(s) = \{s\} + \mid S_{0} \mid$.  Is this enough to say that $\pi$ is surjective?  It seems as if I am simply repeating the definition.  Is it "more correct" to say something like, there are two vectors $s_{\alpha}, s_{\beta} \in S$ such that $s_{\alpha} + s_{\beta} = s \implies$ $\pi(s_{\alpha} + s_{\beta}) = \{s_{\alpha} + s_{\beta}\} + \mid S_{0} \mid$, which is equivalent to $\{s\} + \mid S_{0} \mid$?

Answer (score 2):

The map $\pi:Y\to Y/X$ sends a point $y$ to its class $y+X$, which is a coset, as you write. As a set, $y+X$ is the set of elements $u$ in $Y$ that are equivalent to $y$ modulo $X$, i.e. such that $u-y\in X$. Now, for any $(z+X)\in Y/X$ we have $$\pi^{-1}(z+X)=\{y\in Y\,|\,y-z\in X\},$$ which contains at least $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since the cosets in $Y/X$ are necessarily determined by exactly what $\pi$ does. To be more clear, you can probably even use a contradiction: if $\pi$ is not surjective, there exists $y\in Y$ such that $y+X\not \in \text{im}(\pi)$. But for all $y\in Y$, $\pi(y)$ is defined, and equal to $y+X$. Thus $\pi$ is surjective.